# Add description to table cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a table that has three columns. In one of these columns (in the photo it is in the middle), I would like to add a small description below (for example, the operation system of the device).
I tried several options with Grid, but nothing worked for me. Perhaps you can help me?

For a better idea, I marked the desired result in the photo in green

[image]

```
return (
    <TableRow sx={TableRowStyle}>
        <TableCell size='medium' align='left' sx={TableCellIdStyle}>
            {
                (props.id === '-')
                    ? ""
                    : <DeleteHidePacketButtonGroup packetReference={null} isHidden={null} />
            }

        </TableCell>
            <TableCell size='medium' align='left' sx={TableCellIdStyle}>{props.id}</TableCell> /*This TableCell is responsible for the central column */
            <TableCell size='medium' align='right' sx={TableCellIdStyle}>
                {
                    nextPage !== undefined ? <a className="page-links" onClick={showList}>List of {nextPage}</a> : null
                }
        </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what UI framework you are using, but generally, a `TableCell` should not be inside another `TableCell` directly. For your issue, you can create a `div` inside your center table cell. Set it to `display: flex; flex-direction: column`. And put your content inside that div.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your advice, unfortunately it doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing something like this. Could you provide an example with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `title` attribute in HTML element,
Basically, the title attribute gives you the default description box from the browser's end

```
<tr>
    <td title="This is discription" onClick={...} styles={{...}}>
    {...}
    </td>
</tr>
```

in your case,you can even try this by targeting element

```
cell.setAttribute('title', "This is discription");
```

And yes,
you can not add another `<Tablecell/>` inside `<Tablecell/>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick snippet that hope it helps (based on some sample code from MUI). Column 2 has what you probably need:

```
const addTextInCell = () => (
  <div>
    <div>Device 1</div>
    <div>Android</div>
  </div>
);

const rows = [
  { id: 1, col1: "Hello", col2: "World", col3: "Column 1" },
  { id: 2, col1: "MUI X", col2: "is awesome", col3: "Column 2" },
  { id: 3, col1: "Material UI", col2: "is amazing", col3: "Column 3" }
];

const columns = [
  { field: "id", hide: true },
  { field: "col1", headerName: "Column 1", width: 150 },
  {
    field: "col2",
    headerName: "Column 2",
    width: 150,
    renderCell: () => addTextInCell()
  },
  { field: "col3", headerName: "Column 3", width: 150 }
];

const TestTable = () => (
  <div style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }}>
    <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
  </div>
);

export default TestTable;
```

I am using the renderCell method where you can specify what your cell will render. In the 'addTextInCell' function you can have you HTML which in this case is just a simple `<div>` containing two more `<div>` which will give you the desired result (you can replace it with anything you want).